# Spring boot Multi threaded Scheduler

Tags: spring-boot

I want to run 3 different scheduled tasks.

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "00 30 05 * * *")
    public void task1(){
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 20, fixedDelay = 2700000)
    public void task2(){
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "00 45 05 * * *")
    public void task3(){
    }
```

Task 2 will run for at least 25 minutes. if task 2 started at 05:25, the other two tasks were not executed as planned.

So, I updated the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler as follows

```
    final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("custom-scheduled-task-pool-");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

    scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
```

Even after modifying, it is not executing as expected.

Could you please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: How do you test that task1 and task3 are not being executed?
You have scheduled time for `00 30 05 * * *` so, task1 will be executed only when the time matches with this. same for task3 too

Comment: While testing I changed the time accordingly. For better understanding, I have given a sample cron expression.

Comment: To me, it should work fine. Not seeing any problem with your sample code then. If not done yet, set breakpoint or print something inside those tasks and give it a try

Comment: I tried breakpoint and the control never reached